# Framedrops with Cocos2d-android when the game activity resumes

Tags: java, android, cocos2d-android

I'm trying out some game engines for android and came across [cocos2d-android-1](https://github.com/ZhouWeikuan/cocos2d).
I've set up a small example that pretty much does nothing except to show a FPS counter to start with.

The problem is that every time the activity goes to the background (via the home or back key) and comes back, the FPS drop a lot. At the first start they are around 60 for me (HTC Desire), after resuming the activity they stay below 10.

The activity is fixed to landscape in the manifest and uses `@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen` to enable fullscreen mode.

When I stop the app from the applications menu in the device settings it resets everything. The first launch gets 60 fps again, next launch drops too.

How can I fix this?

Here is a small working sample:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private CCGLSurfaceView glSurfaceView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        glSurfaceView = new CCGLSurfaceView(this);
        setContentView(glSurfaceView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        CCDirector.sharedDirector().attachInView(glSurfaceView);
        CCDirector.sharedDirector().setDisplayFPS(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        CCDirector.sharedDirector().pause();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok fixed it. Apparently I forgot to call resume() on the director.
Added this to the above code and it works fine:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    CCDirector.sharedDirector().resume();
}
```